How do I solve this kind of error while tring to run migrations in django
raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.
I was expecting it to run migrations in django in the data base 'my sql' for the accounts app

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
